# how to call a powershell script of another directory in azure devops

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to call a powershell script from another powershell script which is in a sub-directory. Directory structure is as below:

```
main_script.ps1
./Test:
.  ..  test.ps1
```

So i am calling main_script.ps1 from the test.ps1 as below:

```
#Call the main script
../main_script.ps1
```

When i am doing that from the cloud shell with the same structure, i can call the main_script.ps1 script succesfully. But in azure devops i am having the error below:

```
##[error]The term '../main_script.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Do you have any idea about the correct path? What is the default path of azure devops task? I am using Azure Devops Release to create the pipeline.

Comment: check the "working directory" of the powershell script task

Comment: You should specify the folder where `test.ps1` exists in the working directory of the powershell script task. That because the default work folder is `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you have any idea about the correct path? What is the default path of azure devops task?

Since you are Azure Devops **Release** to create the pipeline, the default path of azure devops task should be `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory`, `C:\agent\_work\r1\a`.

However, our powershell scripts should locate under the path：

`System.DefaultWorkingDirectory`\`_System.TeamProject`

So, to invoke the `main_script.ps1` in the `test.ps1`, we could use following scripts to achieve it:

```
Param(
 [String]$Workfolder,
 [String]$TeamProject
    )

echo $Workfolder

Invoke-Expression "$Workfolder\_$TeamProject\main_script.ps1"
```

**Note:** Do not ignore the short underscore `_`.

The important things is that pass the parameters  `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory` and `System.TeamProject` to the `main_script.ps1` in the `test.ps1`:

My powershell task:

[image]

Then the test result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks that workingDirectory is just appended to a script name without changing root directory. You can overcome this calling script inline:

```yaml
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2  # this doesn't work
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    targetType: 'filePath' # Optional. Options: filePath, inline
    filePath: 'test.ps1'
    workingDirectory:  '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/stackoverflow/77-powershell/'

- task: PowerShell@2 # this works
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline' # Optional. Options: filePath, inline
    script: |
        cd '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/stackoverflow/77-powershell/'
        ./test.ps1
```

Comment: Where are the maintainers for this task? https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks claims to not be responsible: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/10996

Comment: In option one (`filePath`), the `filePath` input also needs to have parameter `Build.SourcesDirectory`:
`filePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/stackoverflow/77-powershell/test.ps1'`